# Matlab: What does the second argument in max(A,[],dim) mean?

Tags: matlab

I was just using `max` function on a specific column of a matrix and the syntax got me wondering:

What does this empty matrix passed as the second argument mean?

```
max(A,[],dim)
```

I know it's probably for separating it from `max(A,i)` which does the comparison. But, why an empty matrix?

Does it have a certain meaning? Is this kind of argument used in other functions like this?

Comment: Have not tested this, but with the introduction of `~` you can now skip input and output arguments in recent Matlab versions. I suppose the usual solution will eventually become: `max(A,~,dim)`

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin, I didn't know about `~`. Thanks for the info. Currently though, I tested it and `[]` can't be replaced with `~` (at least not in this case).

Comment: I don't believe that `~` can be supplied as a placeholder for an input argument when you're calling a function. Only in the argouts list. As an input arg, it only works in the argument list of the function definition (that is, line 1 of `foo.m`) as a way of saying "this function implementation ignores this argument, regardless of what the caller passes in".

Comment: @AndrewJanke, you're right. I checked the docs and as you said, it can whether in calling a function for ignoring output values, or in function definition for ignoring passed values as input.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Actually, your guess is right. Since Matlab is not a strongly typed language and there is no classic function overloading technique, a function must guess of a meaning of an argument by the context. Mathworks wanted to merge both finding maximum within a single matrix and along of two arrays in a single function.

Thus they need to separate these cases somehow. And they use an empty matrix `[]` as a placeholder. Otherwise, they won't be able to separate cases `max(A, dim)` and `max(A, B)`. They could have used any special variable for this purpose, but `[]` is the fundamental construction.

Comment: +1 for the good explanation. As a side note: do you have any other function in mind with the same usage of `[]` (apart from min/max)? I'm curious to know whether it's a general thing in Matlab or just in this case.

Comment: @Mahm00d It's often used in the optimization functions, such as `fmincon` to get to the final `options` parameter without specifying all the inequalities which may not be relevant. It's quite common across the board with more complex functions that take a lot of parameters.

Comment: @Dan, so basically it's used for skipping some parameters, right? As in default parameters?

Answer (score 2):

It's allows you to compare two equal sized matrices to find the elementwise max. See the [docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html). Using `[]` as an input is just a way to skip ahead to a later input.

Comment: As far as I see in the docs, that's the `dim` argument, not the empty matrix one.

Comment: @Mahm00d sorry you're correct,I was thinking of the second output instead of the second input. I'll correct it now.

Answer (score 2):

The `max` function performs comparison of value pairs by default. Entering `max(1,2)` will obviously output `2`. As another example, using `max(x,0)` is a neat way of performing half-wave rectification of `x`, comparing each value of `x` to the single value of `0`. To compare the elements of a single matrix with the values contained within that matrix, the second argument can be specified as an empty matrix `[]`. This acts as a flag to the function to compare values within the one matrix.

You'll see an empty value `[]` being used in many Matlab functions throughout the documentation. This often indicates a default value is to be used, or changes the mode of operation of the function.

Answer (score 2):

This has already been answered well, but, for completeness, let's imagine what it would look like if they didn't do this. To compare two values it would become:

```
max([A B])
```

We have extra, unnecessary square brackets, but it's like doing `xlim([0 1])`, so not a problem. But watch what happens if A is a vector and B is a scalar you want to compare against:

```
max([A; repmat(B, 1, numel(A))])
```

We already have something horrible in comparison to `max(A, B)`, and you can imagine what happens with matrices and higher dimensions. And you also have to decide whether you need a comma or semicolon after "A".

Comment: Not only that, but how would you distinguish `max([A B])` from `max(A)`? The function gets a single array as input in both cases. `A` can have any number of dimensions, so you can’t use that to distinguish. Plus, concatenation can be expensive when the arrays are large. You could make an argument for `max({A,B})`, that could be usable.